# GoogleApiClient is not connected yet , on a location application

Tags: android, service

im trying to get the city and country from a location but i am catchinf an exception : GoogleApiClient is not connected yet

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_weather);`
`if (checkPlayServices()) {
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        createLocationRequest();
    }

    displayLocation();
    togglePeriodicLocationUpdates();}
private boolean checkPlayServices() {
        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this, PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "This device is not supported.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
                finish();
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
    }

    private void displayLocation() {

        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
                .getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            double latitude = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
            double longitude = mLastLocation.getLongitude();
            Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            try {
                List<Address> address = geoCoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
                city = address.get(0).getLocality();
                country = address.get(0).getCountryName();


            } catch (IOException e) {
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            }


        } else {

            Toast.makeText(this, "erreur", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        displayLocation();
        if (mRequestingLocationUpdates) {
            startLocationUpdates();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection failed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = "
                + result.getErrorCode());

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        checkPlayServices();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected() && mRequestingLocationUpdates) {
            startLocationUpdates();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        stopLocationUpdates();
    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // Assign the new location
        mLastLocation = location;

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Location changed!",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // Displaying the new location on UI
        displayLocation();

    }

    private void togglePeriodicLocationUpdates() {
        if (!mRequestingLocationUpdates) {

            mRequestingLocationUpdates = true;

            // Starting the location updates
            startLocationUpdates();

            Log.d(TAG, "Periodic location updates started!");

        } else {
            // Changing the button text

            mRequestingLocationUpdates = false;

            // Stopping the location updates
            stopLocationUpdates();

            Log.d(TAG, "Periodic location updates stopped!");
        }
    }

    protected void createLocationRequest() {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FATEST_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(DISPLACEMENT); // 10 meters
    }

    protected void startLocationUpdates() {

        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);

    }

    protected void stopLocationUpdates() {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,this);
    }
```

does anyone know why i am getting this Exception , because i already connected the api in the onStart() method !!

any answer would be helpful :D

Answer (score 0):

onCreate() gets called before onStart(), so you are requesting the location before you have connected to the Google API.

Here is the lifecycle diagram from the Android Dev site: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

[image]